# I want to retrieve two values from uniquely identified data in firebase

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

that's my database

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-MdgDcU3Zb-TiLlTwfwU" : {
      "email" : "t1@email.com",
      "fname" : "test",
      "lname" : "1",
      "password" : "t1",
      "phoneno" : "304*******"
    },
    "-MdgNDN23XCTyB4DsF4W" : {
      "email" : "t2@email.com",
      "fname" : "test",
      "lname" : "2",
      "password" : "t2",
      "phoneno" : "333*******"
    }
  }
}
```

that's the login activity's code

```
    DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("phoneno").equalTo(userphoneno);

    checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.exists()){

                //editTextphoneno.setError(null);
                //editTextphoneno.setErrorEnabled(false);

                String passwordFromDB =snapshot.child(userphoneno).child("password").getValue(String.class);

                if(passwordFromDB.equals(userpassword)){
                    //editTextphoneno.setError(null);
                    //editTextphoneno.setErrorEnabled(false);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Login_page.this, Bottomnav.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }else{
                    editTextpassword.setError("Invalid Password");
                    editTextpassword.requestFocus();
                }
            }else{
                editTextphoneno.setError("Invalid Phone Number");
                editTextphoneno.requestFocus();
            }
        }
```

I want the user to login through his phone number and password but every time, after entering phone no and password I click on login, the app crashes. What I have understood is that may be the user's phone number and password is not being retrieved successfully.

Comment: Are there any errors in the logcat? Can you please share them?

Comment: @Dharmaraj 2021-07-03 18:46:24.706 7152-7152/com.example.testmechin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testmechin, PID: 7152
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.testmechin.Login_page$2.onDataChange(Login_page.java:62)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:191)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)

Comment: at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6971)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the following query:

```
DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("phoneno").equalTo(userphoneno);
```

It means that you are searching the "users" node, for all users who have the "phoneno" equal to "userphoneno". This also means that such a query may potentially return multiple results. Even if the query returns a single result, you'll need to loop through the DataSnapshot object using getChildren() method, as in the following lines of code:

```
checkUser.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String passwordFromDB = ds.child("password").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", passwordFromDB);
                //Add your logic
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Please see that inside `onComplete`, in order to get the password, there is no need for a `.child(userphoneno)` call, as the "password" is already a child of the DataSnapshot object.

More important, **never** store sensitive data as passwords in plain text. Malicious users might take advantage of that. Use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) for that and secure the database using [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).